# Vscode Downloading Vs Code Server forever

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote

My Vs Code not working well when I tried connect docker to code into it. I don't know why, but I suppose that upgrade broke my project. Before it, the setting was working very well.

I took a picture and ask how can I fix it.

[image]

Comment: Happens for me at least last half a year... Container is on ssh machine  connected via VPN.

Comment: I tried waiting for around 10 minutes and it downloaded. Don't know why although ✨